# How to authorize a key to sftp only, and only to a subdirectory?

Tags: sftp, authorized-keys

I need to allow `sftp`-only access to an account on a machine, where *I do not have root*, so that a remote user can upload (`put`) files to a subdirectory, and nothing else.

Not having root-access prevents me from following the numerous existing examples/tutorials, because they all talk about modifying `sshd_config`.

My plan was to set the authorized key's `command` thus: `command="internal-sftp -d %d/dump -pls,put"`. The idea being, that sftp-service will start in `~/dump/` and that, with only the `ls` and `put` allowed, the user will not be able to escape it even if he wanted to.

Unfortunately, if I give the `command` *any* arguments, the sftp-connections disconnect immediately after the authentication succeeds. There are no errors on the client-side, and, without root, I cannot see the server logs.

Even if I remove the `-p` flag, it still disconnects right away... Only the barebones `"internal-sftp"` works, but then the remote can see -- and overwrite -- *anything*, including the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` itself.

Can one add an sftp-only key to one's own `authorized_keys` reliably, without changing the global settings?

(Yes, it might be, that the user can "escape" by `put`-ting with an explicit path, but I cannot even test it...)